# How to write distinct query in Elasticsearch 7.6.2

Tags: elasticsearch-aggregation

I am new to ES. My requirement is to fetch last n recent timestamp and distinct trace_id along with their records. Like in the sql query "Select distinct trace_id, job_name from stpjoblogs where status="SUCCESS"". Please let me know how to achieve the same in Elasticsearch 7.6.2.

My response would be:

```
_source" : {
          "port" : 57376,
          "job_name" : "stbl-executive-dashboard",
          "timestamp" : "2020-04-28T10:55:45.640267+00:00",
          "trace_id" : "180600fd27ef8108",
          "PCF_Space" : "Development",
          "PCF_Org" : "EPSOrg",
          "status" : "SUCCESS"
        }
```

and I tried with below query:

```
GET /stpjoblogs/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
       "must": [
         {"match":{"status":"SUCCESS"}}
         ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "timestamp": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "aggs": {
    "distinct_transactions": {
      "terms": { "field": "trace_id"}
    }
  }
}
```

But I am getting below error

```
{
  "error" : {
      "caused_by" : {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [trace_id] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memory."
      }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Comment: Did it resolve your query?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add trace_id.keyword. If index is created by automapping this field will be already present or  you need to this in mapping

```
"trace_id":{
   "type":"text",
   "fields":{
      "keyword":{
           "type":"keyword"
       }
    }
}
```

```
GET /stpjoblogs/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "status": "SUCCESS"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "timestamp": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "aggs": {
    "distinct_transactions": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "trace_id.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "job_names": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "job_name.keyword",
            "size": 10
          },
          "aggs": {
            "docs": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 1,
                "sort": [{"timestamp":"desc"}]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To get latest document for a trace_id, you can use  [field collapsing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-collapse.html) , it works like Group by and returns top one document per field

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "status": "SUCCESS"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "collapse": {
    "field": "trace_id.keyword",
    "inner_hits" : {
            "name": "space",
            "collapse" : {"field" : "job_name.keyword"},
            "size": 3
        }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "timestamp": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jaspreet. I was expecting group by(filed collapse) only. Could you please let me know how we can do collapse with multiple field.?

Comment: @HShetty I have updated answer using both terms and collapse

Comment: Thank you Jaspreet for your quick response. I used updated changes(multi level collapse) and noticed below output. I got multiple row data in the response which has same trace_id and same job_name but diff timestamp. Actually I should get one record which has recent timestamp.  However  If I use one level collapse for trace_id I am getting expected output(only one row). Have you these kind of issue?                           Also let me know if you aware, how can I write these collapse query in my java API.

Comment: @HShetty I have updated  terms query. In case of multilevel group , it will be more appropraiet to use it